# What type of view Is this, (Ipad Related)

Tags: objective-c, ipad

can someone please identify what type of view this is, as i want to implement it. but have just moved over to ipad from iphone and have no idea

Thanks

[image: Ipad view]

Comment: Are you referring to the view container with the little white dots along the bottom (as on the iOS apps screen) that you can flick across? I'd like to know what this is too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be a UIScrollView in [paging mode](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html) with custom subviews.

But only the developer of this views knows for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a stock view, it’s a custom view with an image view, some labels, etc.